# Document Similarity calculation with Okapi Scheme

Tags: java, lucene, similarity

I have found Okapi Similarity measure can be used to calculated document similarity from here http://www2002.org/CDROM/refereed/643/node6.html and from this paper http://singhal.info/ieee2001.pdf

I want to calculate similarity between documents of a document collection using Okapi similarity scheme with Lucene

e.g. I have 10 documents (doc #A,#B, #C, #D etc.) in my document collection. I ll pick a document as query document. Say doc #A.
Then for each term=1..n , of query document I ll calculate the

```
idfOfQueryTerm = log (totalNumIndexedDocs - docFreq + 0.5)/(docFreq + 0.5)
```

then I ll take the `sum of (idfOfQueryTerm) from 1 to n`;  `idfOfQueryDoc= sum of (idfOfQueryTerm)`
Then for each 10 documents(Including query doc), I l calculate total term frequency of document by this equation, based on the query terms of the query document that was selected first.

```
tfOfDocument={2.2 * termFrq }/ { 1.2 * ( 0.25 + 0.75 * docLength / this.avgDocLength ) + termFrq }
```

So I ll end up with 10-`tfOfDocument` values, one for each document and one `idfOfQueryDoc` value.

Then I can calculate the similarity between query document and other documents using these two methods.

1)  Similarity between query doc and doc #B= `idfOfQueryDoc* tfOfDocument #B`

2)  Similarity between query doc and doc #B= `idfOfQueryDoc* tfOfDocument #B* tfOfDocument#queryDoc`

I want to know, whether my understanding of Okapi Similarity measure is correct?

Which method of above two will be optimal for calculating the doc similarity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the first link, the similarity between the query document and another document is:

```
sim(query, doc) = sum(t in terms(query), freq(t, query) * w(t, doc))
```

where (from the second link, slightly modified as I think the formula in the link is incorrect)

```
w(t, doc) = idf(t) * (k+1)*freq(t, doc) / (k*(1-b + b*ls(doc)) + freq(t, doc))
ls(doc) = len(doc)/avgdoclen
```

and `idf(t)` is your `idfOfQueryTerm`, `freq(t, doc)` is the frequency of term `t` in document `doc`.

Choosing b=0.25 and k = 1.2 you get

```
w(t, doc) = idf(t) * 2.2*freq(t, doc) / (1.2*(0.25+0.75*ls(doc)) + freq(t, doc))
```

*Note*: the two links give slightly different equations, although the differene is mostly in weighing, not the fundamentals